# spark scala memory management issues

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to submit a spark scala job with below configuration:

```
spark-submit --class abcd --queue new --master yarn --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 4g --driver-memory 2g --num-executors 1
```

The allocated space for the queue is 700GB and it is taking entire 700GB and running.
Is there a way to restrict to 100GB only?

Thanks in advance.